# Batch/bash/executable for changing permission of user in Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, configuration, persistence

I made desktop app. in Netbeans platform using Java Swing. Now I made installer of my App.  After that I want to change the permission of user when my app. is installed in PC.  I want to make bash file or batch or any executable file for change permission of user.

How to make batch or bash or executable file for changing permission of user in Windows?

Comment: when myApp insall in windows,then i have to change the config file of myapp.so first of all i have change permision of user from read only to Modify control.so i want to make batch or executable file for this perpose.

Comment: Don't you need administrator privileges to make such a change?

Comment: i want adminstrator privilegesfor such change.

Comment: [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) should prompt the user automatically for this.

Answer (score 2):

> I made installer of my App.

A good installer for Java desktop apps. is [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> i have to change the config file

It is more common to extract the config. details from a read only file or resource (e.g. an entry in a Jar) and store them in a 'known place'.  Common choices for that place are:

- The [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API that can persist name/value pairs.
- The JWS based [`PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html) can also store config. details but provides stream based access, so it can handle a wider variety of information (e.g. `Properties` file for name/value pairs, or a serialized object or XML.. for more complex configuration settings that go beyond name/value pairs). 
  Here is a [demo. of the `PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps). The demo. stores text.

Comment: Am i correct to infer that a JWS application can use a `PersistenceService` from the sandbox, i.e. no elevated <security>? I'm guessing that such a cached JWS application need not trigger UAC on Windows.

Comment: @trashgod *"Am i correct to infer that a JWS application can use a PersistenceService from the sandbox, i.e. no elevated <security>?"*  Yes.  The sand-boxed version of the JNLP for the demo. has no security element at all. *"I'm guessing that such a cached JWS application need not trigger UAC on Windows."*  I am pretty sure 'no it won't trigger UAC', unfortunately my site is running very slow, so I am unable to confirm that at this moment.